# AngularFire2 Query list on multiple values

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Is it possible to query a Firebase List on multiple keys and values, I have list look like following

```
{
  -key1: {
    type: 'type1',
    completed: false
  },
  -key2: {
    type: 'type2',
    completed: true
  },
  -key3: {
    type: 'type2',
    completed: false
  }
}
```

Is it possible to fetch all from the list that contains both `type` equals `type2` and `completed` is `true`

following is my code

```
let end = FIREBASE.LIST_END;
this._angularFireDatabase.list( end, {
  query: {
    orderByChild: QUERYABLES.TYPE,
    equalTo: type
  }
});
```

but this will only query on types how could I add the other key `completed` too?

Answer (score 1):

No Firebase only supports queries on a single attribute. You could make "composite keys" for yourself though.